# Phantom Field Creation (Negative Kinetic Energy Scalar Field)

Tags: internal-consistency, science-fiction, physics

I'd like to create a scenario a few decades to a century in the future where an experiment (attempting to create a wormhole to Luna on Earth via quantum foam mining) gone wrong causes a phantom scalar field to be created on Earth along with a Bronnikov-Ellis drainhole unintendedly leading to Low Earth Orbit (LEO). For the sake of this question, let's say the phantom scalar field spans a ~50-100 km radius area

My understanding of phantom scalar fields is that the matter within them has negative kinetic energy. That is, if you (a being of positive mass particles exerting positive kinetic force) push on a ball of this negative matter, it will be "pushed" towards you. If it's rolling away from you, you push it away from you to slow it down.

1. Do I understand correctly that all matter within this field then becomes exotic matter with a negative kinetic term?
2. Is it at all plausible that the only result of this would be 1)? I mean, no massive hydrogen-splitting nuclear explosions or anything like that from all matter suddenly turning negative?
3. Would it effect human bodies in any kind of immediately deadly way if all of someone's mass particles suddenly turned negative?
4. Finally, I've read that wormholes have mass at least equal to the mass of the negative matter sustaining them. Would it be implausible to say that this drainhole into LEO actually orbits earth?

The intent is for a massive, catastrophic event to occur because of this. Not world-ending, but more like something that might destroy an entire city or ~50-100 km-radius area, before the drainhole is stabilized into a Bronnikov-Ellis wormhole.

Comment: One question per post, please.

Comment: "Would it effect human bodies in any kind of immediately deadly way if all of someone's mass particles suddenly turned negative?" I imagine it'd probably be pretty hard to move if all your muscles suddenly started working the opposite way. Might hake it hard to breathe, too, though maybe it'd just result in you breathing in on the exhale, and breathing out on the inhale? It also seems possible that it might fuck up biochemistry pretty bad  but I'm not a biologist

Comment: Surely it would hurt in the morning at least ;o)

Comment: @nick012000 is that a plausible result of being caught in a phantom scalar field? It seems logical, but I have no idea if our model of math/physics would support that- but yeah, that's exactly the type of thing I'm looking for wrt 3)

Comment: @L.Dutch Sorry, first post :). Would it be okay if I rephrased the question so that there was only one main question, but left room for answerers to tell me I'm wrong about assumptions I'm making, or would that be meta-gaming the "one question per post" rule?

Comment: @PandaBearTellEm It should be fine, then if the answers here kick-up issues that require additional work you can ask new questions later.